# How to construct a transversal of three lines with given ratio?

Tags: geometry

Let the pairwise skew lines $a$, $b$, $c$ be given in the three dimensional Euclidean space. Construct a line $l$ that intersects the given lines in $A$, $B$, $C$, respectively, such that $\frac{AB}{BC}=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: As you write “construct”, what kind of construction tools are you allowed?

Comment: Originally this is a problem on descriptive geometry, and I meant to construct it using any description method (e.g. axonometry, Monge projection) and Euclidean constructions. Your solution is great, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Project your whole scene orthogonally onto a plane which is orthogonal to $b$. In that plane, you have a single point $B'$ which will be the image of both $b$ and $B$, and two lines $a'$ and $c'$ which are the images of $a$ and $c$ under this orthogonal projection. Then take line $a'$ and construct lines $g_1$ and $g_2$ parallel to $a'$ but at twice its distance from $B$. There are two such lines, one on either side of $B$. Intersect these lines with $c'$ and you obtain two points $C'_1$ and $C'_2$. Connect them with $B'$ and intersect with $a'$ to obtain $A'_1$ and $A'_2$.

[image: Illustration in the plane]

Now project these points back onto $a$ and $c$ and you obtain $A_1,A_2,C_1,C_2$. Their connection will intersect $b$ in $B_1$ and $B_2$.